# algorithm of sorting d sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, insertion-sort

Please help to understand the running time of the following algorithm
I have d already sorted arrays (every array have more than 1 element) with total n elements.
i want to have one sorted array of size n
if i am not mistaken insertion sort is running linearly on partially sorted arrays
if i will concatenate this d arrays into one n element array and sort it with insertion sort
isn't it a partially sorted array and running time of insertion sort on this array wont be O(n) ?

Answer (score 3):

Insertion sort is **O(n²)**, even when original array is concatenation of several presorted arrays.  You probably need to use [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) to combine several sorted arrays into one sorted array.  This will give you **O(n·ln(d))** performance

Answer (score 2):

No, this will take quadratic time. Insertion sort is only linear if each element is at most a constant distance *d* away from the point where it would be in a sorted array, in which case it takes O(*nd*) time -- that's what's meant by partially sorted. You don't have that guarantee.

You can do this in linear time only under the assumption that the number of subarrays is guaranteed to be a small constant. In that case, you can use a [*k*-way merge](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/kwaymerge.html).

Comment: @MAB: never mind, I made a mistake. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is fairly (relatively) linear for **small** values of N.  If N is large then your performance will more likely be N^2.

The fact that the sub-arrays are sort wont, I believe, help that much if N is sufficiently large.

[Timsor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)t is a good candidate for partially sorted arrays

Comment: isnt the running time of insertion sort on partially sorted arrays linear ? if i concatenate this arrays wont be partially sorted ?

Comment: Yes, but in your case the entire array isnt partially sorted, just "sub" parts. In other words if only a few entries are out of place then insertion sort is decent - but in your case you have parts that are sorted - but the "whole" is still relatively unsorted.

Comment: I think that this: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ is very educational ( was for me anyway :-) )

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are known to be sorted, it's a simple matter of treating each array as a queue, sorting the "heads", selecting the smallest of the heads to put into the new array, then "popping" the selected value from its array.

If D is small then a simple bubble sort works well for sorting the heads, otherwise you should use some sort of insertion sort, since only one element needs to be placed into the order.

This is basically a "merge sort", I believe.  Very useful when the list to be sorted exceeds working storage, since you can sort smaller lists first, without thrashing, then combine using very little working storage.